# Child element does not stretch when overflowing

Tags: html, css

I have a container div with overflow auto. When a child element has long text it will overflow the container causing it to show x-scroll. So far no problem.
The issue is that the child element does not stretch with the container width including the available scroll causing it to look cut off when scrolling the container:

```css
.flex-col {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.h-full {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  overflow: auto;
  resize: horizontal;
  min-width: 10rem;
  max-width: 25rem;
}

.item.selected {
  background-color: green;
  color: red;
}

.item {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex flex-col h-full">
  <div class="h-full container">
    <div class="flex p-2 items-center item selected">
      <div class="flex items-center">-</div>
      <div class="whitespace-nowrap">1Loooooooooooooong text that does not wrap.... aaaaaaaaaa sssssssss ddddddddd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex p-2 items-center item">
      <div class="flex items-center">-</div>
      <div class="whitespace-nowrap">2Loooooooooooooong text that does not wrap.... aaaaaaaaaa sssssssss ddddddddd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex p-2 items-center item">
      <div class="flex items-center">-</div>
      <div class="whitespace-nowrap">3Loooooooooooooong text that does not wrap.... aaaaaaaaaa sssssssss ddddddddd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/690j7bsw/

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common issue while using `whitespace-nowrap` with `overflow` property.

To fix this, you need to change `display: flex` to `display: inline-flex`.

Like this:

```
.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

This is because block elements take 100% width even if the text is not wrapping. This is not the case with inline elements. They always take the width of the content, that's exactly what we're leveraging here.

Note: You can rename the class `flex` to `inline-flex` to make it more intuitive.

https://jsfiddle.net/3xo0gq1p/

Answer (score 0):

Add the *selected* class to the div-element with the long text

Next adjust your CSS selector to `.item .selected {...}`

Comment: I need to include both divs (the one with - and the one with the text) in the selected div

Answer (score 0):

Just add `width: fit-content;` to `.item`:

```css
.flex-col {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.h-full {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  overflow: auto;
  resize: horizontal;
  min-width: 10rem;
  max-width: 25rem;
}

.item.selected {
  background-color: green;
  color: red;
}

.item {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: fit-content; /*  */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex flex-col h-full">
  <div class="h-full container">
    <div class="flex p-2 items-center item selected">
      <div class="flex items-center">-</div>
      <div class="whitespace-nowrap">1Loooooooooooooong text that does not wrap.... aaaaaaaaaa sssssssss ddddddddd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex p-2 items-center item">
      <div class="flex items-center">-</div>
      <div class="whitespace-nowrap">2Loooooooooooooong text that does not wrap.... aaaaaaaaaa sssssssss ddddddddd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex p-2 items-center item">
      <div class="flex items-center">-</div>
      <div class="whitespace-nowrap">3Loooooooooooooong text that does not wrap.... aaaaaaaaaa sssssssss ddddddddd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```